# Jquery mobile getJSON works in browser but not in mobile device

Tags: android, jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have project on Jquery mobile 1.4.5 where I load data from local JSON data and parse them as a list. When I test it in firefox it works ok, the list is populated, everything is ok, but when I compile it in cordova and android, on the mobile device the list from json is not populated. I keep the data.json file in the root folder of the www project files. What can be the problem?

```
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.sometext) {
        output+="<li " + 
        "blah blah blah"
        "</li>" ;
    }
    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
```

in my config file of the cordova i have:

```
 <content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: try replacing data.json with the url from where you are getting the json

Comment: but I want to build an offline app, the json data I want to be saved in the users device.

Comment: http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/loading-a-json-file-from-www-folder-with-phonegap/  check this out, it may help

Comment: What error when ajax fail?

Comment: In firefox no errors the Json file loads ok, in chrome I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users.........../data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. In the device how can I get these kind of errors?  In Chrome I wasnt surprised with the cross origin error, since i thought that building the app with dordova and <access origin="*" /> would solve this....

Comment: I think I found the problem. The script that gets the Json data file was not in the index.html page but only in a second page that i wanted to load the json data in. when I renamed the page to index.html, the json data loaded!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, this solved it for me:

If you use Prepros or another web dev tool, you probably forgot to upload your json file to FTP. Then it would work fine on the localhost but not in the url.